# External SanDisk 64GB USB doesn't mount or seem to have a file system

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, disk-utility, filesystem, disk-format

I recently bought a SanDisk 64 GB USB.  It will not mount and doesn't reformat as there are no partitions/no file system.  I'm not sure how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Does it appears in Disk Utility (found in /Applications/Utilities)? If yes you can just select the drive and erase it to initialize it.

Comment: The name *Anisha* and the size of 67 MB suggest that it is broken. [SanDisk RMA](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5232/~/return-material-authorization-(rma)-process)

Comment: @TomShen only the hardware itself shows up, not any bootable partitions so there is nothing to erase unfortunately.

Comment: @klanomath thanks for this - ill see if i can sort out a replacement.

Comment: @James Please search Google for "Anisha 67 MB" (or 64 MB). You will find several SanDisk related results with some methods to restore/create a partition - a lot of them weren't successful though

Comment: @klanomath Ohh ok so other people have had this issue - thanks for bringing that to my attention.